# Rotating proxies while connected to a server - PHP

Tags: php, proxy

Is it possible to switch proxy ips while still connected to a server or do I have to disconnect to use another proxy ip? Is this possible in PHP?

I have a proxies.txt file with about 3 proxies. When connected to a server through the proxy, lets say the proxy is no good while connected (it timeout, abort or disconnect) I want to be able to switch to another proxy in the txt file wile the transmission with the server is still live. (I think it isn't because if the proxy disconnects or aborts from the server the transmission is ended).

Anyone can confirm this with some sample PHP code?

Comment: What kind of transmission? Is it a TCP stream?

Comment: It depends a lot on what you are trying to accomplish. If you are doing curl stuff, then you can do anything you want as long as you are using same cookie file and server does not bind your session to an IP address.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of transmission it is. Sorry I am new to PHP. I think there is just UDP and TCP but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: Dimi thanks for your response. What I want is to scrape a directory website. Whitepages.ca to be specific.

Comment: Frz im not 100% sure but I think its a TCP stream.

Answer (score 0):

After reading what Dimi said I used google and found this:
http://rotateip.com/proxies-in-scraping-with-php-and-curl

And all is well now.

Thanks everyone.